# How to connect RoboFlow model to React Native Expo Camera

Tags: react-native, expo, roboflow

I want to connect my roboflow model to my react native app so I can input user taken photos directly to my model to display results. How would I go about doing this?

Here is a link to my code:
https://snack.expo.dev/@www112358/jealous-soylent

I tried using Axios to make a POST req to the model but it doesn't seem to work, my code results in a error

Answer (score 0):

are you using the example code snippets we have available to make the request?

https://docs.roboflow.com/inference/hosted-api#code-snippets